# Validating a reset password token fails in one method, but works in another in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

We're trying to use the `UserManager` to generate a `PasswordResetToken` and verifying it, before actually resetting the password.

The first method is responsible for the generation of the token, which is then sent to the user via a password reset link.
The generation of the token works fine and when validating it after, the `VerifyUserTokenAsync` returns true (line: `//var result = await this.userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, TokenOptions.DefaultProvider, UserManager<User>.ResetPasswordTokenPurpose, token);`

The second method is for resetting the password. We're not using the `UserManager.ResetPassword` because our user doesn not have all the required fields. 
When calling `VerfiyUserTokenAsync` in this method, if returns `false` even though the provided token is exactly the same as in the first method.

We can't wrap our heads around why it works in the first method, but fails in the second...
Any clue would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```
[HttpPost("generatepasswordresettoken")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GeneratePasswordResetToken([FromBody] ResetPasswordTokenRequest resetPasswordTokenRequest)
{
    var user = await this.userService.GetAsync(resetPasswordTokenRequest.Email);
    var token = await this.userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
    //var result = await this.userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, TokenOptions.DefaultProvider, UserManager<User>.ResetPasswordTokenPurpose, token);

    return this.Ok(new GenerateResetPasswordTokeResponse {ResetPasswordToken = token, Email = resetPasswordTokenRequest.Email});
}



[HttpPut("resetpassword")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<IActionResult> ResetPassword([FromBody] ResetPasswordRequest resetPasswordRequest)
{
    var user = await this.userService.GetAsync(resetPasswordRequest.Email);
    if (await this.userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, TokenOptions.DefaultProvider, UserManager<User>.ResetPasswordTokenPurpose, resetPasswordRequest.ResetPasswordToken)) {
        var resetPasswordDomainModel = this.resetPasswordMapper.Map(resetPasswordRequest);
        if (await this.userService.ResetPasswordAsync(resetPasswordDomainModel)) {
            return this.Ok();
        }
    }

     return this.BadRequest("Couldn't reset password");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each SecurityToken should be valid just for one operation and this behavior of *VerifyUserTokenAsync* method is an advantage. 
Otherwise you need to write some code to do control this behavior by yourself. In your case, you can generate new token then pass its to *ResetPasswordAsync* method.

```
    [HttpPut("resetpassword")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ResetPassword([FromBody] ResetPasswordRequest resetPasswordRequest)
    {
        var user = await this.userService.GetAsync(resetPasswordRequest.Email);
        if (await this.userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, TokenOptions.DefaultProvider, UserManager<User>.ResetPasswordTokenPurpose, resetPasswordRequest.ResetPasswordToken))
        {
            var newtoken = userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
            resetPasswordRequest.ResetPasswordToken = newtoken;
            var resetPasswordDomainModel = this.resetPasswordMapper.Map(resetPasswordRequest);
            if (await this.userService.ResetPasswordAsync(resetPasswordDomainModel))
            {
                return this.Ok();
            }
        }

        return this.BadRequest("Couldn't reset password");
    }
```